# How to make a garbage bin?

Tags: cleaning, home, kitchen

How do you make your own garbage bin, provided you already have a bag for it? I've tried using empty boxes, like the banana boxes produce departments give away. This never really worked well. Also there's something unappealing about having a bag full of garbage in the corner of the kitchen floor so I would prefer not to just use a bag.

Note, I don't care if the solution is to "make" a garbage bin or find a substitute tool for holding the bag and keeping it tidy.

Answer (score 3):

1) Upside down bar stool. Drape bag over the ends of the legs:

[image: Upside down barstool]

2) Improvised Tupperware container. Take lid off, cut bottom off large container (leaving ring of plastic), place garbage bag over container (with most of bag hanging through hole), seal with Tupperware lid:

[image: Tupperware bag holder]

3) Magnetic board: use two strong magnets to hold the bag to board, with slack side to allow open bag.

4) Use a PVC 5 gallon bucket or diaper pail.

Comment: the stool idea is genius. Up-vote.